# Django cannot display model fields to template

Tags: django

I have a model from a package I would like to retreive fields from for the user to my template but am struggling to get this to work as I have done with user model previously:

**models**

```
class DeviceManager(models.Manager):

    def devices_for_user(self, user, confirmed=None):

        devices = self.model.objects.filter(user=user)
        if confirmed is not None:
            devices = devices.filter(confirmed=bool(confirmed))

        return devices


class Device(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User'), help_text="The user that this device belongs to.", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="The human-readable name of this device.")
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Is this device ready for use?")

    objects = DeviceManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            user = self.user
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            user = None

        return "{0} ({1})".format(self.name, user)
```

**view**

```
from django_otp.models import Device

def account(request):

    user = request.user

    device = Device.objects.all()

    context = {"user": user, "device": device}

    return render(request, 'account.html',context)
```

**template**

```
{{ device.name }}
{{ device.confirmed}}
```

I am getting the folowing error:

AttributeError: Manager isn't available; Device is abstract

I have also tried to change

```
device = Device.objects.all()

# To

device = DeviceManager.objects.all()
```

But the produces the following error:

AttributeError: type object 'DeviceManager' has no attribute 'objects'

Help is much apprecaietd in displaying the content from model to my template. Thanks

Comment: try Device.objects.devices_for_user(user, confirmed)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t actually query abstract models like this. I’d suggest looking at [Multi-Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)